# How do I display timezone as text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to be able to display the system timezone as separate plain text in my app when it launches:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString* date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    lblDate.text = date;

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSString* zone = [gmt:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
txtTZ.text = zone;`
```

My app can display the date correctly but crashes upon the timezone.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSString* zone = [gmt:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
txtTZ.text = zone;
```

With this:

```
NSString *zone = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] abbreviation];
txtTZ.text = zone;
```

Comment: Works just great. Thanks!  Can I use the same string to display a zulu time zone? Ex: Los Angeles is -8 GMT but +8 in the zulu time zone.

Comment: It will display whatever the devices time zone is set to. From the docs: The time zone currently used by the system. If the current time zone cannot be determined, returns the GMT time zone.